# How do I pass an HTML element reference to a component in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a component `MyNodeComponent` that takes a `target` HTML element as **input**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-node',
  templateUrl: './my-node.component.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class MyNodeComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, AfterViewInit {
  @Input() target;

  ...
}
```

The problem is I am not sure how to send an HTML DOM node to target in a dynamic fashion. Especially as there could be multiple instances of MyNode on a page with different hierarchical relationships:

```
<body>
  <my-node target="???"></my-node> <!-- target should refer to target1 -->

  <p id="target1" #target1>Hello</p>

  <div id="target2" #target2>
    Goodbye <my-node target="???"></my-node> <!-- target should refer to target 2 -->
  </div> 
</body>
```

I tried putting the id name ('target1', for example) in the target attribute but it just showed up as a string. Most suggestions I see involve using `@ViewChild` which does not seem to work for my purpose as it requires using an explicit name in the component that should appear in the HTML. Because there could be multiple instances of a component I don't want a dependency on what the #id name should be.

Comment: `[target]="target1"` (which is not the ID of the element, but the template variable #target1). That's probably a bad idea though: you should generally avoid using the DOM in components. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: That worked- I'll research the brackets here to understand why (this is binding related?). Can you explain why it is a bad idea? I'm creating a component which submits a target HTML node to the Html2Canvas library so that the rendered component can be turned into an image.

Comment: In that precise case, it's fine. You need the brackets because otherwise, the value passed to the input is the literal string "target1", instead of the result of the evaluation of the Angular expression "target1".

Comment: If you want to post an answer here I can give you the checkmark. I'll also be posting another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59062387/how-do-i-create-an-htmlelement-reference-in-an-angular-component

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create an HtmlElement Reference in an Angular component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59062387/how-do-i-create-an-htmlelement-reference-in-an-angular-component)